# Moment js validating edge case, dates like feb 30th

Tags: date, validation, momentjs, luxon

I want to validate if the following date is valid : 30 Feb 2021.
So the main issue is 30 Feb 2021 shouldn't be a valid date or 31 April 2021. is it possible to achieve that with moment js or luxon? or should i use another approach?

```
   let m = moment([2021, 2, 31]);
   console.log("Date is valid", m.isValid()); \\returns true which is not a valid date!
```

Comment: As stated in the [dedicated parsing section of the docs](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/array/): _**Note:** Because this mirrors the native `Date` parameters, months, hours, minutes, seconds, and milliseconds are all zero indexed. Years and days of the month are 1 indexed._, so you are creating a moment object for the 31th of March that is a valid date.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know moment.js or luxon , but it's achievable in basic JS (although a little long-winded)

JavaScript will up-tick the date, so the 29th of Feb is the 1st of March.

Therefore we can compare the before and after version :

```
var month = 1; // zero based - 1 is feb
var day = 30;
var year = 2021;

var testDate = new Date(year, month, day); // will convert to 2nd of March

var parsedDate = testDate.getDate(); // will be 2
var parsedMonth = testdate.getMonth() // will be 2 , zero based, March
var parsedYear = testDate.getFullYear(); // remains 2021 in this case

var isValidDate = parsedDate === day && parsedMonth === month && parsedYear === year;
```

This could be condensed a lot but I've made it as bloated as possible for readability

you could easily turn it into a function, something like this (untested)

```
function IsValidDate(year, month, day){
 var InputMonthsAreOneBased = 0; // change to 1 if needed
 var testDate = new Date(year, month - InputMonthsAreOneBased, day );
 return testDate.getDate() === day && testdate.getMonth() === (month - InputMonthsAreOneBased) && testDate.getFullYear() === year;
}
```